# SQL Count with Grouped aggregates

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am trying to write a SQL query that allows me to create a line chart with historical data. I am trying to figure out how many of my users are using each build of my app as time passes (per diem basis). My Y-Axis is going to be the Percent of usage (out of 100) of all apps, the X-Axis is the day, and each build is a different line. At any moment in time, all the line's sums should equal 100%.

As this query should be grouped by Version/Build, in addition to the date, I am trying to figure out how to get the percentage of total users for any given day in my query. I am able to get this query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sub.Version, 
    sub.Build,     
    sub.app_id, 
    sub.Users, 
    sub.`day`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
        FROM snowplow_enricher_good seg
    ) AS Total,
    (sub.Users/Total) * 100 AS Percent
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        visitParamExtractString(seg.contexts, 'version') AS Version,
        visitParamExtractString(seg.contexts, 'build') AS Build,
        seg.app_id,
        seg.`day`,
        CONCAT(
            Version, 
            ' (', 
            Build, 
            ')'
        ) AS AppBuildVersion,
        COUNT(DISTINCT seg.user_id) AS Users
    FROM snowplow_enricher_good seg
    GROUP BY Version, Build, app_id, `day`
    ORDER BY Users DESC
) AS sub
WHERE sub.app_id = 'APPID';
```

Note that the current percentage shown is the percent of all days, not the single day. I tried creating a `WHERE` clause within my custom `FROM` statement, but that failed.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupArray

```
SELECT
    totalCnt,
    totalSum,
    ga.1 AS tag,
    ga.2 AS value,
    (value / totalSum) * 100 AS percent
FROM
(
    SELECT
        count() AS totalCnt,
        sum(value) AS totalSum,
        groupArray((tag, value)) AS ga
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            tag,
            value
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AS tag,
                [10, 100, 50, 100, 40] AS value
        )
        ARRAY JOIN
            tag,
            value
    )
)
ARRAY JOIN ga

┌─totalCnt─┬─totalSum─┬─tag─┬─value─┬────────────percent─┐
│        5 │      300 │   1 │    10 │ 3.3333333333333335 │
│        5 │      300 │   2 │   100 │  33.33333333333333 │
│        5 │      300 │   3 │    50 │ 16.666666666666664 │
│        5 │      300 │   4 │   100 │  33.33333333333333 │
│        5 │      300 │   5 │    40 │ 13.333333333333334 │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out using a series of joins and subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    day, 
    app_id, 
    version, 
    version_count, 
    app_count, 
    (version_count / app_count) * 100 AS percent
FROM (
    SELECT 
        day, 
        app_id, 
        visitParamExtractString(contexts, 'version') AS version, 
        count(DISTINCT user_id) AS version_count
    FROM 
        snowplow_enricher_good
    where 
        day >= subtractDays(today(), 30)
    GROUP BY 
        day, 
        app_id, 
        version
) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        day, 
        app_id, 
        count(DISTINCT user_id) AS app_count
    FROM 
        snowplow_enricher_good
    WHERE 
        day >= subtractDays(today(), 30)
    GROUP BY 
        day, 
        app_id
)
USING 
    day, 
    app_id
WHERE
    app_id = 'APPID'
ORDER BY 
    day DESC, 
    app_id, 
    version;
```